# How to access specific key through nested dictionary from print statement/function?

Tags: python

a={'a':{'b':6,'g':9,f:'9'}}

Want to access key `'g'` in python dict from a print statement?

```
print("(a):{}".format(a.get('a'['b'])))
```

I have tried like this it is not working.

Comment: Just a simple indexing. `print("(a):{}".format(dictionary['a']['g']))`

Comment: How to access same key using variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it either inside of the format string:

```
print("a: {[a][g]}".format(data))
```

Or just by indexing it normally:

```
print("a: {}".format(data["a"]["g"]))
```

Comment: How to access the same key using variables?